# Angular custom directive doesn't load when returning to page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular custom directive that works the first time it's loaded on the page with the same `controller`.  When I leave the page, go to another page/controller, and then return to the original page containing the directive, the `directive` doesn't load.  The return to the page is coming from a different controller.  There are no errors on the console.  It doesn't even debug into the directive `link`.

This is the the directive

```
app.directive('customdirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        debugger;            
        map = L.map(attr.id, { zoomControl: false }).setView([40.000, -30.000], 0);
    }
};
});
```

It's in the page like this

```
    <customdirective id="customd" style="height:100%;"></customdirective>
```

I'm going to the page using angular routing

```
var location = "/PageName"
$location.path(location);
```

This is the flow of what happens.  Page2 contains the directive.

```
                    (directive loads)                         (directive doesn't load)
Page1/Controller1 -> Page2/Controller1 -> Page3/Controller2 -> Page2/Controller1
```

Comment: @bto.rdz The only console error is when I return to the page. It's happening because it's trying to reference an object that isn't set because it happens in the directive which isn't being called. This is the error. `TypeError: Unable to set property 'setLayer' of undefined or null reference at Anonymous function`

Comment: What's in your link?

Comment: @Scottie All that's in it is `debugger; map = L.map(attr.id, { zoomControl: false }).setView([40.000, -30.000], 0);` right now.  It's only being called the first time.  The second time coming from a different controller doesn't even get to the `debugger`.